# CakePHP 4 - Problem with dashed routing and parameters

Tags: cakephp-4.x

I'm trying to create a link to a page defined by a year, stock symbol, and account_id.
so the link I want is, e.g.,

```
<a href="/reports/position-income/2020/IBM/2" class="navlink">2020</a>
```

My link creation looks like:

```
<?= $this->Html->link($year, ['controller' => "reports", 'action' => 
    "positionIncome/$year/$symbol/$account_id;"], ['class' => 'navlink']); ?>
```

Unfortunately, the link() method is (I assume) trying to create a dashed route, so it's  hyphenating (and lowercasing) the all-caps stock symbol, so I get:

```
<a href="/reports/position-income/2020/i-b-m/2" class="navlink">2020</a>
```

Which doesn't work.

I've been playing around in routes.php to try to change this behavior, but nothing's worked so far.

Can anyone suggest a solution other than creating the link manually, which is my current workaround?

Thanks.

Comment: How about `['controller' => 'reports', 'action' => 'positionIncome', $year, $symbol, $account_id]`

Comment: Thanks Greg.  I came to the same realization about a half-hour ago and just finisihed testing it.  That's the correct answer.  I also posted it at about the same time you were posting yours.

Answer (score 0):

Solved.  This was a case of understanding where the parameters go in the link() function.  They should be at the end of the url array:

```
$this->Html->link($year,
   ['controller' => 'Reports',   
    'action' => 'positionIncome', $year, $symbol, $account_id],
   ['class' => 'navlink']);
```

Works now.